# DatePickerDialog in Android, date validation

Tags: android, validation, datepickerdialog

I have a simple activity where a user needs to choose date(date only, without time). I need to make a correct validation. Firstly, i thought to put dayOfMonth, monthOfYear and year into 3 different Text View, then using "if else" write conditions such as (if day <= 0 or >= 31 ...). The code i tried:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Date.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            tvDay.setText(dayOfMonth);
                            tvMonth.setText(monthOfYear);
                            tvYear.setText(year);


                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work, i can put dayOfMonth, monthOfYear year only into 1 Text View. Like this:

```
       public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Date.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            tvDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

How would be correctly to make validation in my case? It is probably stupid question, so sorry, but i am newbie.

Thank you.

Comment: Why you need a validation in here?you don't need a validation  if you use datepickerdialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` and then `calanderObject.getTime()` will give you a well-formatted date in the form of a `String`

Here I'm passing a reference of a `TextView` inside the method. It's not important though.

```
private void setDate(final TextView tV) {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            cal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            tV.setText(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
        }
    }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dennis is right i just want to add that for date validation you can use calendar object ,it has all this cool operation like match it against today's date like

if(someDate >= now){
...

it's much easier then try implement it on your own , if you have calculation that need to consider leap year (the day of 29/2 every 4 years) then you should use GregorianCalendar which inherit from Calendar .

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html